# Print the "approval" sign/check mark (✓) U+2713 in Python

Tags: python, unicode

How can I print the check mark sign "✓" in Python?

It's the sign for approval, not a square root.

Comment: You are looking for unicode character: U+2713.

Comment: `python -c "print '✓'"` executed just fine http://ideone.com/dTW5D8

Comment: ^^ check here, it may help? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm

Comment: If it doesn't work it might be your terminal not supporting unicode if memory serves me.

Comment: Does your terminal have a character encoding and font that supports this character?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can print any Unicode character using an escape sequence. Make sure to make a Unicode string.

```
print u'\u2713'
```

Comment: I like this way. How do you know how to print each unicode character?
Is there some exhaustive list of characters?

Comment: I just use trusty Google :). The following site looks pretty promising if you don know what you are searching for: http://unicode-table.com/

Comment: There's also a list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), which I use from time to time.

Answer (score 27):

Since Python 2.1 you can use `\N{name}` escape sequence to insert Unicode characters by their names. Using this feature you can get check mark symbol like so:

```
$ python -c "print(u'\N{check mark}')"
✓
```

Note: For this feature to work you must use unicode string literal. `u` prefix is used for this reason. In Python 3 the prefix is not mandatory since string literals are unicode by default.

Answer (score 16):

Solution [defining python source file encoding](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

print '✓'
```

http://ideone.com/dTW5D8

Comment: Does this also affect output encoding or does that still need to be specified?

Comment: nope, output encoding has to be treated separately (at least in Python 2.x). The `#coding`-line only tells the interpreter how to interprete the source code.

Comment: The above solution is a somewhat implicit: since @chico is not using a unicode string, the string is already implicitly encoded – with the source file's encoding. If you changed the encoding of the file, it would also change the output encoding. You'd be better off writing `print u'✓'.encode('utf8')`.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
print u'\u2713'.encode('utf8')
```

The encoding should match the one of your terminal (or wherever you are sending output to).

Comment: This is something I was looking for a while

Comment: @Philipp This answer is from 2013, when Python 2 was still cool. Today you probably (hopefully) have Python 3 running, where this snippet raises a SyntaxError. If you *are* running Python 2, however, then you probably need to replace `'utf8'` with the encoding used by your macOS terminal, as pointed out in the answer.

Comment: Ah :D that’s the reason!

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, just print it:

```
print("✓")
```

If your code still needs to run on *both* Python 2.x and 3.x:

```
# coding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals

print("✓")
```