# Trying to print check mark U+2713 in Python on Windows produces UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, printing

I have read through [Print the "approval" sign/check mark (✓) U+2713 in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16676101/how-to-print-the-approval-sign-check-mark-%E2%9C%93-in-python), but none of the answers work for me. I am running Python 2.7 on Windows.

```
print u'\u2713'
```

produces this error:

> exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: character maps to

This:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
print '✓'
```

does not work because I am using Windows.

```
print u'\u2713'.encode('utf8')
```

Prints out âœ“, which is not the right character.

```
print('\N{check mark}')
```

Is just silly. This prints `\N{check mark}` literally.

Comment: Thumbs up for doing some research and explaining exactly why the other question's answers don't help you. You don't have to be quite so aggressive about it, though. :)

Comment: Note that [the `print('\N{Check Mark}')` answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20799954/603977) seemed to be assuming Python 3 and thus missing the important point that the [printed string must be a `unicode` rather than a `str`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16076802/603977).

Answer (score 1):

Read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and you will understand what is going on.

The bad news is: you won't be able to print that caracter because it simply is not available in the default text encoding of your Windows terminal. Modify your terminal configuration to use "utf-8" instead of the default "cp-852" or whatever is the default for Window's cmd these days,  and you should be good, but do so only *after* reading the above article, seriously.

Comment: In principle true, except that you actually can't set the Windows command prompt to UTF-8. (You can try code page 65001, but there are serious bugs in the MSVCRT that make this unusable.)